# How to Extract Data from a field with multiple values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

IP.Nexus puts custom fields into a table all muddled up into one row and some how pulls the correct data out.

basically my custom fields row looks like so:

```
a:2:{i:2;s:4:"Test";i:3;s:10:"Accounting";}
```

How do i select what item to pull as i would like to out put just one item not the whole row, is it with delimiters or string splitter, as i am novice with this part of mySQL

Cause i would like to echo out just the advertising on its own and also vice versa for the testing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also i would like to put it into a variable, and echo out that varible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a serialized array using [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function so you can get its contents using [`unserialize($YourString);`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

But I see that you string is corrupted for deserialization, because `s:4:` in `s:4:"advertising"` says that after `s:4:` 4 character long string is expected that `advertising` is not.

Comment: sorry mixed them around advertising should be where test is and vice versa.

Comment: am i correct in saying this will work to out put the "Test" section ?

<?php



$string1 = $row["ads_fields"];
$cfarr = unserialize($string1);

echo $cfarr[2];


?>

Comment: Way, happy days, i must of just been having a mind blank. Thanks and i guess is the same for advertising but [4]? as multiple delimiters in the middle?

Comment: If it's index is `4` of course. To check indexes you can do something like: `print_r($cfarr);`

Comment: @Thank you PLB, great stuff, could do with someone like you on my forums haha, but thank you again saved me alot of database work.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the database is in serialized(json) form.You can turn it into simple array using `unserialize`.
For example;if `$mystr` is your string
write

```
$mystring=unserialize($mystring)
```

You will get normal array of this string 
You can do

```
foreach($mystring as $str){
$ads[]=$str['advertising'];
}
```

and the resulting array `$ads` will be the ads you like in simple array form

Comment: so to speak
$string1 = $row["ads_fields"];
$mystring=unserialize($string1)

That would then unserialize the content from that field. but then could i output a select of that deserialized content into a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Since this looks as JSon, you can use a [PHP JSon](https://www.php.net/json) module to parse each row from MySQL.

```
<?php

(...)
while (...) {
    $obj = json_decode($row);
    // do something with $obj
}
```

Comment: Can you explain i haven't seen this before, Sorry.

Comment: Hum ?! What did you haven't seen ? It's some pseudo code, `(...)` mean there's something resumed there.

Comment: @sputnick - the data shown in the question is serialized using PHP's [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) function.  Not JSON at all.  Where did you get the idea it was JSON?